# Using Kotlin, when trying to use the classifier "Intent" error appears saying "does not have a companion obect

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm three weeks in with Android Studios and Kotlin and I'm trying to get the toolbar's dropdown options to redirect to a different page when clicked. But when trying to use
    Intent settings = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class), a red line appears under the first Intent with the error "Classifier 'Intent' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here". What am I missing? fyi, I was copying directly from a video.

[Image depicting red line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE8b0.png)

Thanks!

Comment: You're copy-pasting Java code into Kotlin files. Android studio should've asked you if You wanted to auto-convert though.

Comment: Okay. That's weird because the guy in the videos was using kotlin and it worked for him. Anyways, do you know the kotlin version of that line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Java syntax in Kotlin and that is why you're getting the error.
The correct syntax for what you are trying to do is this:

```
val settings = Intent(this, SettingsActivity::class.java)
```

Please take a look at the [basic syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#basic-syntax) page of the official docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
```